# Debian wake up from suspend password

Tags: debian, password, suspend

I am using Debian Squeeze.

When I suspend my laptop and wake it up again later, it doesn't ask for the system password. How do I fix this?

Comment: What system password? If you mean a BIOS password, that's beyond Linux's purview. If you mean the root password, that's highly unusual. If you mean the user who's currently logged in on the console, that's more usual, but then the password would be that user's password.

Comment: What desktop environment is this?  Gnome, KDE, something else?

Answer (score 3):

If using GNOME, go to System/Preferences/Screensaver and check "Lock screen when screensaver is active".